How can I present a set of information efficiently using a heterogeneous graph that I'll code later?
I am trying to present a set of information (premises, inference rules, conclusions, attacks) with a heterogeneous graph as described here. For instance, I have the following information:
The object appears red therefore the object is red unless the object is illuminated by a red light.
For this I have designed the following graph.
My Query : Is this graph efficient enough to present such information considering that the actual graph may have hundreds of instances of each type of node and edge and I will code this later? If not, what modifications can be made to this design?


Is it a math question? What do you mean by "efficient enough"?

This question involves in presenting information in a text using a graph. So, it involves first order logic and data structure (heterogeneous graph). By 'efficient enough' I meant a design of a graph that will be efficient in terms of implementation (writing code). The final graph will contain hundreds of such nodes and edges of each type.

Your question is probably more suited for cross-validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/, which has topics such as data mining and machine learning.

Is your question more or less asking for a specific data structure ?

@caduk I've already posted on CV. They closed my Q.

@JeanMarie : U can say that. It will definitely be a graph. I have to design the graph efficiently.


Do you know "Prolog" langage ? It could be helpful for the design of a "toy-version" of your "semantic graphs"


Thanks @JeanMarie. I'll explore that.

I think you should look at the so-called "modal logic".

Correctness is more important than Optimality
We should ideally consider "efficiency" only after we have ensured "Correctness" , which is missing here.
I have got some bad news for you. I presume you are here to learn , hence you will take this negative feedback to know where you are going wrong.
ISSUES :
Premise given is "Object appears red" , there is no Premise that "Object is illuminated by a red light" , yet the graph is wrongly showing that
Conclusion is [ "Object is red" or "Object is illuminated by a red light" ]
We see that the graph is claiming the Inference Rule [ "Object appears red" $\implies$ "Object is red" ] , which is not only wrong , it is not even a rule.
The Correct Inference Rule is [ "A" , "if A then B or C" , hence "B or C" ]
In your Case , The Correct Inference Rule is [ "Object appears red" , "if object appears red then Object is red or Object is illuminated by red light" , hence "Object is red or Object is illuminated by red light" ]
I am annotating your graph with that analysis :

POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS :
I am not sure what your "Syntax" is for showing OR , hence I am making my own. With that Caveat , here is "ONE" Correct graph in outline format , though there are Syntax variations & graphs variations :

We can make it "Efficient" by reducing the number of nodes to make smaller graph like this :

Based on the Syntax Details , we could make it more "Efficient" , though that is after we make it "Correct" , logically.

Thanks for your valuable feedback. I'm trying to present a knowledge base, described in a paper, using a graph. Could u plz see the paper specially page no 2091, 2097 and 2098? The nodes and edges have been chosen according to the explanations in page 2098.
Link to the paper: https://academic.oup.com/logcom/article/27/7/2089/2917886
